# How do I reverse an array with the current function without using arr.reverse()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been completely stuck on this one. I only know how to use the arr.reverse (). Could someone  please provide me with the correct modification needed to complete the code snipet in the attached picture?

Thank you.

[image: Array reverse]

Comment: have you tried iterating over the array from the back?

Answer (score 1):

There's two main ways you could do it.

1. A pure algorithm that doesn't destroy the input array: just loop the array backwards and insert items in a new one as you go. Takes *O(n)* time & space.
2. An in-place algorithm that mutates the original array: use two-pointers and swap the items. Takes *O(n)* time, but *O(1)* space.

```js
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3]));

function reverseArray(arr) {
  let low = 0, high = arr.length - 1;
  
  while (low < high) {
    const lowVal = arr[low];
    arr[low++] = arr[high];
    arr[high--] = lowVal;
  }
  
  return arr; //no need to return as input is mutated, but could be useful anyway
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```js
function reverse(arr) {
    let temp = []
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        temp.push(arr[i])
    }
    return(temp)
}
```

Comment: Careful here, `temp` would be a global variable as you haven't used `var`, `let`, nor `const` to declare it. Using `const` would be best as you don't expect the variable to change. You also don't need the extra parenthesis around the return value and ideally you'd use `let` to declare the `i` variable so that it's block-scoped within the for loop.